# Fullcalendar New data when click on button next

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am creating a calendar FullCalendar, inserting the events from an external page e

```
events: {
            url: '/fullcalendar/calendar/json/eventi.asp',
            error: function() {
                $('#script-warning').show();
            }
        }
```

I would want to again load the data when him click on the keys next and prev.

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.fc-prev-button', function() {
        //load new data

        });
```

I have succeeded in putting the script for the event on the button but I don't succeed to recall new data.

If it were possible I would want to recall the data using a page to which send three parameters.

Comment: Can we have fiddle ?

Comment: @ShashankShah Sorry, but I have not understood your question

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @ShashankShah I have not succeeded in putting the script where you tell me. I have loaded here my example [http://www.servexia.fr/fullcalendar/calendar/test.asp]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the refetchEvents method? That is what I have done in the past. This would go in your on click event handler.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

Comment: I have tried this way:
         $('body').on('click', 'button.fc-prev-button', function() {
   
  
    events: [
    {'title': 'p a\n Phone:3356555555 11_1218223'}
    ];
   
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    
   });

Comment: I have loaded here my example [servexia.fr/fullcalendar/calendar/test.asp]